# Is there any way in JavaScript to call a function declared inside the scope of another function by using its name available in string format?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, javascript-objects

Please tell if the below would be possible without making `function fun`a method of an object.

```
(function a() {
var fun = function() {
console.log('abc');
}
var x = 'fun';
// call fun using x (How ?)
})();
```

Comment: There's always `eval`. But it never should be used for this. Why are you trying to do this, what is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `eval`. This will evaluate the string as JavaScript code.

```js
(function a() {
var fun = function() {
console.log('abc');
}
var x = 'fun';

eval(x)();
})();
```

Comment: That is not the same function, its a copy but does not have the same closure (the reason you would have a function within a function) so its behaviour would not match as it does not have access to the same data.

Comment: @Blindman67 What are you talking about? Nothing is copied here. `eval(x)()` behaves the same as `fun()`.

Comment: @Bergi I presume that the answer was for the question. "Access the function outside the enclosing function" and that the given snippet is not what this answer means, as that is pointless as there is already access to the function where the eval is.

Comment: Ok readed the question,. he just wants access from within the function...

Answer (score -1):

I always prefer to use window variable to execute my function instead of using eval, also I remember that some browsers throws warnings when you use eval. Also at chrome extensions is not enabled by default.

So in my case, you can set a function into windows global variable like this:

```
windows.x = function(){
    // do something here
}
```

and then execute it like this:

```
windows["x"]()
```

Comment: That's essentially a method of an object, which the OP asked to avoid (for whatever reason). Of course using an object would be the proper way, but using global variables for this is really wrong.